# How to create a fixed indent?

Tags: indentation

I'm trying to convert my CV from word to tex. The attached image shows the general layout, which I can't figure out how to mimic with LaTeX. On the left margin is a year (e.g. 2023) and then that lines up with a citation/information on the right. I want the text to the right of the year to be aligned to the same place horizontally on the page.

Here is my best attempt, which isn't working out very well.

Thanks for adivce!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Peer-Reviewed Publications}

In-Prep

2023 or 2024 \quad\quad
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  Zoe Todd, Nicholas Wogan, David Catling (2023). Environmental influences on the formation of ferrocyanide and implications for prebiotic chemistry. In-prep.
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{3mm}

2023 \quad\quad
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  Zoe Todd, Nicholas Wogan, David Catling (2023). Environmental influences on the formation of ferrocyanide and implications for prebiotic chemistry. In-prep.
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{3mm}

2023 \quad\quad
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  Nicholas Wogan, David Catling, Kevin Zahnle (2023). Earth’s impact history and the timing of the origin of life. In-prep.
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{3mm}
Submitted
\vspace*{3mm}

2023 \quad\quad
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  Nicholas Wogan, David Catling, Kevin Zahnle, Roxana Lupu (2023). Origin of Life Molecules in the Atmosphere After Big Impacts on the Early Earth. Submitted, Planetary Science Journal.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing this manually, I would use a description list for this kind of format. And proper sectioning commands.

But over time you may want to use something more automated, in which case then using `biblatex` with the `publist` style (documentation can be found [here](https://texdoc.org/pkg/biblatex-publist)) is probably the way to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{cvlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[cvlist]{style=sameline,leftmargin=1in,font=\normalfont}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}

\section{Peer-Reviewed Publications}

\subsection{In-Prep}

\begin{cvlist}
\item[2023 or 2024]
  Zoe Todd, Nicholas Wogan, David Catling (2023). Environmental influences on the formation of ferrocyanide and implications for prebiotic chemistry. In-prep.
\item[2023]
  Zoe Todd, Nicholas Wogan, David Catling (2023). Environmental influences on the formation of ferrocyanide and implications for prebiotic chemistry. In-prep.
\item[2023]
  Nicholas Wogan, David Catling, Kevin Zahnle (2023). Earth’s impact history and the timing of the origin of life. In-prep.
\end{cvlist}


\subsection{Submitted}


\begin{cvlist}
\item[2023]
  Nicholas Wogan, David Catling, Kevin Zahnle, Roxana Lupu (2023). Origin of Life Molecules in the Atmosphere After Big Impacts on the Early Earth. Submitted, Planetary Science Journal.
\end{cvlist}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help.